# NoMethod Error when using the mail() method in a Rails 3.0.3 ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, actionmailer, nomethoderror

I am trying to create a mailer class for a RoR webapp I am working on for a class.  I followed the rails guides steps online, but when I try to call my ActionMailer I get a NoMethodError: undefined method `mail' for MyMailer:Class.

Here's my code for MyMailer

```
def MyMailer.immediate_notification_mail(r, st)

    @url = "myurl"


    st.each do |s|

        mail(:to => s.email, :subject => "Subject")
    end

end
```

I call this method from another class with the folowing line of code:

```
MyMailer.immediate_notification_mail(rp, st).deliver
```

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?  I haven't seen anyone else with this problem.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are setting up a static (class) method.

```
def MyMailer.immediate_notification_mail(r, st)
```

This should be:

```
def immediate_notification_mail(r, st)
```